# two for loops in php

Tags: php

I got this code...it's used two loops for.., can u explain how it's work ? the result is 16

```
for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
    {
       for($j=1; $i<=5; $i++)
       {
          if($i == 1)
             echo $j;
          elseif($i ==2)
             echo $j+5;
       }
    }
```

but if I make like this

```
for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
        {
           for($j=1; $i<=5; $i++)
           {
              if($i == 1)
                 echo $j;
              elseif($i ==2)
                 echo $j;
           }
        }
```

the result is 11.

how can be ?

Comment: Hint: Try to add a new line (\n) after the echo

Comment: What are you trying here? the second loop doesn't have any sense for me.. and probably for nobody..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is same as:

```
$j = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  if ($i == 1) {
    echo $j;
  }
  elseif ($i == 2) {
    echo $j + 5;
    // below is second piece code.
    // echo $j;
  }
}
```

So:

The first piece of code echo `1` and `1+5`, which will be `16`.

The second piece of code echo `1` and `1`, which will be `11`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, your outer loop will run once.

`$i` gets plussed in inner loop, so outer loop runs just once ...

Inner loop will run 5 times and each time `$i` is getting plussed by 1, when `$i` is 1 your printing `$j` which always is 1 so by now you have `1` in output ...

Then when `$i` is 2 you are printing `$j + 5` which will be 1 + 5 = `6`, so you will have `16` in your output ...

So when you change `$j + 5` to just `$j`, you will have `11` in output ...

(You are actually printing 2 separate numbers as string in first code 1 and 6, in second code, 1 and 1)

Answer (score 0):

yup!that is fine.in first internal iteration if(i==1)for that it is 1.remember you are not incrementing j you are printing.so at 2nd iteration i==2 for that it is 1.so finally 1 1...

Answer (score -1):

You codes says 11 and his 16 because he got a $j+5;  (11 + 5 = 16 ;) )

Comment: Yes i didn't meant it has to be summed, i meant that the difference is 5 because the +5.